# How to show $A\times (B\cup C) = (A\times B)\cup (A\times C)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

How to show $A \times (B \cup C) = (A \times B) \cup(A \times C)$, where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are sets. i.e. If $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{2,3\}$ then $A \times B = \{(1,2), (1,3), (2,2), (2,3)\}$.

I started with the proposition, suppose $x$ is an element of $LHS$, i.e. $A \times (B \cup C)$. Help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Max Hi Max, sorry about that, I'll learn for next time, thanks!

Comment: @Programmer Did $\LaTeX$. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a nice tutorial for how to but math in your posts; I would recommend that you learn it!

Comment: @ostrichofevil: Don't forget the titles, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that two sets $A$ and $B$ are equal, it suffices to show that $A \subset B$ and $B \subset A$. I will only show one part.

I am going to show that $A \times (B \cup C) \subset (A\times B) \cup (A \times C)$. First, you need to know that the elements of a cartesian product of two sets are in ordered pairs, so you have to view $A$ as the first set and $B\cup C$ as the second set.

Now let $(x,y) \in A \times (B \cup C)$. This implies that $ x\in A$ and $y \in B\cup C$. This implies that $x \in A$ and $y \in B$ or $C$. This means that $x \in A$ and $y \in B$ or $y \in C$.

Thus, we have that $x \in A$ and $y \in B$ or $x \in A$ and $y \in C$. Hence, you get that $(x,y) \in A \times B$ or $(x,y) \in A \times C$.

Finally, you have $(x,y) \in A\times B \cup A \times C$ and this means that $A \times (B \cup C) \subset A\times B \cup A \times C$.

The reverse case is easy. Its basically using equivalence of this explanation.

P.S: The cartesian product of sets $A$ and $B$ denoted as $A\times B = \{(a,b)\,\,| \,\,a\in A \,\,\text{and}\,\, b \in B\}$

Answer (score 1):

$x \in A \wedge y \in B \cup C\Leftrightarrow(x \in A \wedge y \in B) \vee (x \in A \wedge y \in C)$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for help, but how do I conclude that? i.e. How to show that something something is an element of (AxB)U(AxC)?

Comment: @Programmer (x,y) is in Ax(B U C) iff x is in A and y is in B or C by defintion. Similarly (x,y) is in AxB U AxC iff x is in A and y is in C or x is in A and y is in C.